# With SpringMVC, can I use ftl in a package

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to use spring mvc to provide some function within current system for some reason.
So I want to let it to found the freemarker template from the jar file. Can I set the ftl path as a path in jar?
Maybe similar as below:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath://com.foo.ftl" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="defaultEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes you can; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870750/freemarker-templates-in-several-jars

Comment: thank you! Just what I want.